# Navbar expanded but with one submenu always collapsed

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar which expands at md breakpoint and is made of 2 submenus the collapsing of which is controlled by two buttons with navbar-toggler class.
I want to have my navbar to expand at md but one of my submenu (account) stay always toggled (button that trigger the content show under the navbar).

[image: Here is what I wanna get]

I'm not experimented with js but I guess it's possible to do it via a script. I've also seen in the source code that when the navbar expand the navbar-toggler get display:none which is a problem.

Here is my navbar and a js script to control the 2 submenus collapse:

```js
$('#links').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('#account').collapse("hide");
})
$('#account').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('#links').collapse("hide");
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MYSITE</a>
    <!-- links toggle -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <!-- account toggle -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#account" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="links">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home Page</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Prices</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Who are we</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="account">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign up</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign in</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your javascript `$('#account').collapse()` doesn't get executed because the account div is not yet loaded. Wait for it to load then execute the line, like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('#account').collapse();
}
```

it should do the trick.

Comment: In reality I forgot to remove this line, I already tried this but that does not work. And I think we can modify the collapsed state only if the whole navbar is collapsed.

Comment: This seems working fine as expected. @Hugo  Can you be more clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hum even in jsfiddle that does not work when the viewport is larger than md breakpoint the account button diseapear and is replaced by the links not collapsed

Comment: @cjmling I want to have my account button always visible and that it trigger the account menu show and collapse but with the second button links appear only under md breakpoint

Comment: @Musadiq Khan answer is closer to what I expect

Comment: @cjmling a picture of what I wanna get

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#links').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
      $('#account').collapse("hide");
    })
    $('#account').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
      $('#links').collapse("hide");
    })
        $('#account').collapse()






    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MYSITE</a>
        <!-- links toggle -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- account toggle -->
        <button class="navbar-expand-md" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#account" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="links">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home Page</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Prices</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Who are we</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="account">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign up</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign in</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: That work when the navbar is under md breakpoint but when the navbar is expanded the button is not on the right and the content is shown at the right when we click on the button and not uunder the navbar as a normal collapsed content

Comment: that would be perfect if the content "Sign In Siggn Up" was shown under the navbar